# Explaining Java Code

Tags: java

Can someone explain me the following code step by step:

I can not understand, for example:  `while(0<=--_)$+=(¢.charAt(_)-0x30)<<(_&01l);`

This code is working very fine, But I couldn't understand the code.

```
public String multiply(String ¢) {
    int $=0,_=¢.length();
    while(0<=--_)$+=(¢.charAt(_)-0x30)<<(_&01l);
    return Integer.toString($);
}
```

Comment: We are not here to teach you Java.

Comment: This is the code of a disgruntled employee

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111245/multiply-with-number-1-and-2

Comment: @Marc B u dont need to teach me maybe... i need just help from friendly expert java.

Comment: Perhaps that this code starts making more sense once you replace the odd (obfuscated??) variable names by something more standard.

Comment: Your debugger is your friend when it comes to puzzles like this.

Comment: @ Bathsheba i know but i think there is no problem when someone explain me. but thx a lot of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is deliberately obfuscated code.  Let's start by separating the variable declarations:

```
public String multiply(String ¢) {
    int $ = 0;
    int _ = ¢.length();
    while(0<=--_)$+=(¢.charAt(_)-0x30)<<(_&01l);
    return Integer.toString($);
}
```

Now let's choose meaningful names:

```
public String multiply(String input) {
    int result = 0;
    int position = input.length();
    while(0 <= --position)
        result += (input.charAt(position) - 0x30) << (position & 01l);
    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```

Now you just need to make sense of 0x30 and 01l and the bit manipulation operations << and &, and then maybe it will begin to make sense.  It's still terrible code, but a little bit clearer.

0x30 is the ascii value for 0.

01l is just the value 1 expressed as a long.

<< is the left shift operator

& is the bitwise AND operator.

so the line in the while loop is saying:

add to result, the character at the current position, converted to a digit, bit shifted by the position, ANDed with value 1 (that is to say, only that digit of its value).

Never write code like this and never work with anyone who does.

Comment: Good explanation, not that it matters, but 01 is 1 in octal format, but 010 != 10 (010 == 8) and 0x is hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

At first let us replace those variable names with something more meaningful...

```
public String multiply(String input) {
    int sum = 0;
    int position = input.length();
    while (0 <= --position) {
        sum += (input.charAt(position) - 0x30) << (position& 01l);
    }
    return Integer.toString(sum);
}
```

### Explanation

This function gets a String as input and returns the String value of an int. The while loop runs for each character in the input string. So if the input is "101" it runs 3 rounds. Since $ gets incremented inside the while loop i renamed it to sum. The other names should be trivial.

Now lets figure out what this magic shifting line does...

It gets the number value of the character from the strings and substracts 0x30 (thats 48 in decimal). Thats the ascii value from 0 (zero) and thus removes the offset and makes a '0' character equivalent with 0 as number.

The right part simply is a leftshift by 1 if the length is odd. But don't forget the `--length` from the while loop. The result (if input is a String of numbers) is the sum of the single digits but every second digit gets doubled.

As far as i can tell this method *does multiply*, but it **does not** multiply as you would exspect in a mathematical way from a "multiply" called function.

### Example

If the input is "123456" this function calculates 1 + 2*2 + 3 + 4*2 + 5 + 6*2 = 33.

Further information:
[Wikipedia ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: Thanx a lot of from Germany